# Symfony 5.3.1 model field's default value to current User

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

With Symfony 5.3.1 (and API Platform) I have implemented Security and generated a default User model. Now when someone posts an Article I would like the User object to be associated.

I tried in the Article model's constructor:

```
    /* src/Entity/Article.php */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->submittedBy = $this->getUser();
        // Attempted to call an undefined method named \"getUser\" of class \"App\\Entity\\Article\
    }
```

But it looks like `$this->getUser()` is only available to controllers.

Where is an appropriate place to set this as the default user value for new Articles please?

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways you could do that. The simplest is when you construct the `Article` object, inject the user.

```
/* src/Entity/Article.php */
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->submittedBy = $user;
}
```

Then wherever you do `new Article();` (likely in your controller) you need to change that to `new Article($this->getUser());

There are project that can do all this for you with listeners and so forth like the [Blameable extension here](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions)

But until you understand the basics, I don't recommend moving on.